# angular core has incorrect peer dependency zone.js

Tags: angular, zone

I got the following error while updating my version of angular:

```
@angular/core@10.1.5" has incorrect peer dependency "zone.js@~0.10.3".
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by installing zone.js

```
yarn add zone.js@~0.10.3
```